# Can i switch a title of a action in a notification?

Tags: android, notifications

in my notificationbar i want to switch the title of a action, which I have add with the notification builder. is there a option to switch?
I've tested the following code

```
 notification.addAction(R.drawable.ic_delete, isIgnored?"ignor":"accept", pendingIgnoreEventIntent);
```

but if i build the notification with .build(), only the text is displayed, which are set after the first build.

Has anyone an idea?
greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html):

> To set up a notification so it can be updated, issue it with a notification ID by calling NotificationManager.notify(ID, notification). To update this notification once you've issued it, update or create a NotificationCompat.Builder object, build a Notification object from it, and issue the Notification with the same ID you used previously. If the previous notification is still visible, the system updates it from the contents of the Notification object. If the previous notification has been dismissed, a new notification is created instead.

Comment: jeah of course i can create a new notification and send this with the same notification ID. My problem is, to build this notification i need some informations that only available at the first build. Of course, i can save this informations separately. Or can i extract the informations from a notification?